# How to connect to VAN ( Value Added Network) to download EDI

Tags: file-sharing

Looking to start implementing EDI and I was told that the EDI will be sent through a VAN ( Value Added Network).  How to I access the EDI files?  It used to be sent through FTP.  Do I have to contact the company providing the VAN? or my trading partner?

Answer (score 0):

> I was told that the EDI will be sent through a VAN

Ask these questions to the person who told you this. We don't know anything about your EDI setup.

Comment: Yes I did send them a email I don't know if there is an universal way to connect to VAN thats why I asked here.  Also I don't want to appear like I don't know anything to my trading partners.

Comment: Don't let your ego get in the way of getting the job done. If you don't know something, ask for the details. If you've never worked on EDI before, just say that. Most people have not, it's not some mark of inexperience.,